# FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api) problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

When importing items into my Rails app I keep getting the above error being raised by SearchKick on behalf of Elasticsearch.

I'm running Elasticsearch in a Docker. I start my app by running docker-compose up. I've tried running the command recommended above but i just get "No such file or directory" returned. Any ideas?

I do have port 9200 exposed to outside but nothing seems to help. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting disk watermark related errors/warnings as well?

Comment: @NishantSaini Not that I am aware of.  SearchKick is only returning the error I posted.

Comment: @NishantSaini . Any ideas?  I'm desperate to get this fixed.  I've seen a fix online that says to run `curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" > http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'` .   I have tried this by running it locally, in my app container and my elasticsearch container but none of them work.  They all just return "http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings: No such file or directory" .  Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the `>` symbol from the command. That is causing the error. Use the command as `curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'`

Comment: Also I will suggest you to look at the logs of elastic node. The above command will fix the error but the exact cause of why index is in read-only mode should be found.

Comment: @NishantSaini Ok, I've run that new command and get "curl: (52) Empty reply from server".   When running `docker-compose up` I can see this in the output: "elasticsearch_1  | [2019-01-05T11:06:36,027][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [y3m9dza] flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on [y3m9dza-TfS2SrCOUg8sBg][y3m9dza][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] free: 1.2gb[2.1%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only".  I've just tried importing data into my Rails app but it still hits that problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: @NishantSaini I did run the command purely from my command line, is that correct?  Should I be running it with "docker-compose run"? If so then inside whcih of the containers?

Comment: Ok so as I was suspecting this to be a disk issue. It is the one

Comment: Make sure your elastic container has enough disk available at least 15% should be free

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186224/discussion-between-rctneil-and-nishant-saini).

Answer (score 13):

Indeed, running `curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'` as suggested by @[Nishant Saini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136371/nishant-saini) resolves the very similar issue I ran just into.

I hit disk watermarks limits on my machine.

Comment: i tried this but i got 
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused --- 
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 5

Answer (score 10):

Use the following command in `linux`:

```
 curl -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings?pretty' -d ' {
    "index":{
             "blocks" : {"read_only_allow_delete":"false"}
    }
}'
```

the same command in `Kibana's DEV TOOL` format :

```
PUT _all/_settings
{
    "index":{
             "blocks" : {"read_only_allow_delete":"false"}
    }
}
```